# jQuery script - scroll to div by SVG id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, vector

My code doesn't work (Explanation what code should do, but doesn't work) -
Creates the jQuery function (i.e. it really forces jQuery),
If someone clicks on a div with the st5 class, the function will be executed,
Creating a variable - an id from the clicked div,
Adds to the div to which you want to scroll "active",
Scroll to div -> m + createdvar (id=5 --> m5)

My SVG: https://pastebin.com/tYgkDF93
Code:

```
    (function($){
    $(".st5").on("click", function() {
    var mid = $(this).attr('id');
      $('#m'+mid).addClass('active');
        $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#m'+mid).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: there are no ids in you svg that start with `m`, so the animate function doesn't match anything. That might be the problem.

Comment: It's on page, I don't paste all HTML here

Answer (score 0):

Solution is replace 
        `$(".st5").on("click", function() {`

to 
        `$(document).on("click", ".st5", function() {`